# Incorrect OS name getting in Java

Tags: java, windows-7

Recently I moved on a brand new machine 64-bit Windows 7. But when I run this code, getting the incorrect OS name

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
System.out.println("OS Name = " + osName);
```

The output comes:

```
OS Name = Windows Vista
```

Any idea, what is wrong in my code or system?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe Windows is running your JVM in "Vista mode" (compatibility mode)?

Comment: I am using java.version = 1.5.0_16, due to our project dependency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be using an older version of Java. As this was a known bug(bug_id=6819886) that has been fixed in the newer versions.
[Kindly read this for further details](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6819886).

---

A possible workaround for this in case you are not able to upgrade your java version:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (osName.equals("Windows XP") || osName.equals("Windows Vista"))
    {
       //do something and remember to put in all the names in the above if list. I just added two for example,it will have to include all like Windows NT,ME,95,etc.
    }
    else
    {
        //the block that will be accessible for Windows 7
    }
```

Comment: Then what will be the solution of this problem while using the save java version?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug reported regarding this:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6819886

Not sure if it is fixed in newer versions of Java as I do not have Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

It works on my Windows 7 machine (admittedly a 32-bit one; I don't have access to a 64-bit one right now).

Perhaps your JRE predates Windows 7, and the name is baked into it? Which version of the JRE are you using? I would suggest updating to the latest version and trying again. Admittedly it's pretty nasty if the JRE *does* have the OS names hard-coded into it, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Possible, but I think this is unlikely.

Comment: I am using java.version = 1.5.0_16, due to our project dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Use JAVA-6, I tried its working fine, else your Windows is treating JVM using Vista mode.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem recently. As the [bug 6819886][1] evaluation notes state, you can check the **os.version** property to distinguish between **Windows 7** and **Windows Vista** in this case.

The version for Windows 7 is 6.1 and that for Windows Vista is 6.

```
String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");  
if("6.1".equals(osVersion)){
    System.out.println("OS is Windows 7");
}
```

This way you don't have to upgrade to the latest Java just to make this work.
[1]: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6819886

Answer (score 0):

```
    String winVer = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("95")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("98")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("ME")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("3.51")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("NT 4.0")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2000")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("XP")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("7")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("8")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("8.1")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("10")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2003")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("Vista")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2008")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2008 R2")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2012")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2012 R2")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    } else if (winVer.toLowerCase().contains("windows") && winVer.toLowerCase().contains("2016")) {
        System.out.println(winVer);
    }
```

1. List item

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/8430a707e22b/src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c